# Windows 10 Hibernate Regularly Disabled

Tags: windows-10, hibernate

I sometimes like to use hibernate on my laptop when in the middle of something so that I can just jump right back in with all the applications open where I left them etc.
I enable hibernate using elevated command prompt and powercfg.exe /h on

However after some time, I find that hibernate has been disabled again and I need to rerun the command.

My question is how can I find out what is disabling hibernate? Are there common culprits for this?

If that's not possible, could I create a scheduled task to re-enable it periodically or make a batch file to enable and immediately hibernate that I could add to the start menu?

Answer (score 0):

To find out which process is manipulating hibernation, you may monitor
your computer with
[Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

Start the Filter selection dialog (Ctrl+L), delete the superflous
example filters and set the following to trace the two indications:

[image]

Minimize Process Monitor and let it run in the background while you use
the computer. When the time comes, search (Ctrl+F) for the strings
`shutdown` for the command, and if not found the search for
`HibernateEnabled` for the registry item that controls hibernation.

Once you find the item, double-click it for more information, especially
on the "Process" tab.
If that's not enough to identify the process, look at the other events
that precede or follow to try and find it. If unsure, you may include
the information in your post for us to examine.